# What's the word for the "opposite role" of "Donor"?

Tags: single-word-requests

First post here, please forgive me if wrong community...

By "opposite role", I mean like parent/child, brother/sister.

In organ transplants, the "opposite role" of donor would be recipient. But I'm referring to crowd funding, where the "opposite role" of donor is the person who created the crowd funding campaign that the donor is donating to. They are more than just a recipient, they create and manage their fund raising campaign. gofundme uses the term "campaign organizer" but I'm looking for a single word.

And BTW, what is the correct term for "opposite role"? It's not antonym or "opposite word", because it's not really an opposite relationship.

**EDIT**

The best word for the *reciprocal* of **donor** in the context of crowd funding is **fundraiser**.

It's not a duplicate question because in this context which is more specific, we get a different answer. And the best answer for the word for "opposite role" is **reciprocal** (noun). (e.g., What is the reciprocal of parent? Answer: child)

Comment: You can use the word **fundraiser**. By your  *opposite role*, I think you mean  **reciprocality** ?

Comment: The funder or funders, or fundraisers, are then not the donors, who in turn donate to the recipient  or donee.  Actually the question is unclear, as you've got a donor donating to a fundraiser who's going to give it to the recipients.  Aggregators of funds collect money one way or another and make the donation to the recipients.  This is, then, not a duplicate question.

Comment: @mahmudkoya, I believe you have the best answer. And on the name for the word relationship, it looks like it's reciprocal (noun). Parent is the reciprocal of child. Defense is the reciprocal of Prosecution.

Comment: Oh, then you think fund raiser and donee are the same.  That would indeed make this a duplicate question.  That's not U.S. usage.

Comment: @Xanne, see my edit to my question. I misspoke in my last comment. The fundraiser can be a different person than the beneficiary or they can be the same person. It's the crowd funding platform itself which doesn't have or need a name and is not part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Beneficiary

And it's definitely not the opposite of donor.  It's a pairing that seems to be defined by context.

Examples:

```
Beneficiaries generally receive money or valuables.

Recipients receive gifts or messages

Payees receive what is owed.
```

Comment: Thank you, but there's a more specific term for this context

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps "Benefactor" if what the donor is giving is substantial (an organ transplant). I'm trying to think of how people/organizations respond to me when I make a donation to their cause and, in those cases, they address me by name in any correspondence but I'm likely coded as a "Recipient."

Comment: Thank you, but there's a more specific term for this context

Comment: Check your definition: Benefactor is the donor, not his counterpart.